# What happens if SAME Visual Studio Extension and NuGet DLL are installed in a solution / project

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

For example ASP.NET Core Bundle and Minifier comes both as a [Visual Studio Extension](http://vsixgallery.com/extension/a0ae318b-4f07-4f71-93cb-f21d3f03c6d3/) and [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/). What would happen if I add NuGet package to a solution and then later that solution is opened on machine where the same Extension for Visual Studio has been installed?

Run time problems? One package taking precedence over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it out and it seems that NuGet package takes precedence regardless of version. Even in cases where NuGet package version is lower, it'll run excluding installed extension.

Thinking about it - it makes sense - if you marked something as dependency in your solution it should be higher priority over IDE and it's settings / addins.

Comment: Since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)